# How do I format my HashMap and access specific elements?

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have a .json file in my assets directory that looks like that:

```
{
   "2": {
      "3 darts hint": "D1",
      "2 darts hint": "D1",
      "1 dart hint": "D1"
   },
   "3": {
      "3 darts hint": "1 D1",
      "2 darts hint": "1 D1",
      "1 dart hint": ""
   },
   "4": {
      "3 darts hint": "D2",
      "2 darts hint": "D2",
      "1 dart hint": "D2"
   },
   "5": {
      "3 darts hint": "1 D2",
      "2 darts hint": "1 D2",
      "1 dart hint": ""
   },
   "6": {
      "3 darts hint": "D3",
      "2 darts hint": "D3",
      "1 dart hint": "D3"
   },
   "7": {
      "3 darts hint": "3 D2",
      "2 darts hint": "3 D2",
      "1 dart hint": ""
   }
   [...]
}
```

Then I want to create a HashMap from it, which I do with the following code:

```
private HashMap<String, Object> hashMap;

String json = null;
try {
    InputStream is = null;

    switch (getMatch().getCheckOutType()) {
        case "Straight Out":
            is = getAssets().open("single_check_outs.json");
            break;
        case "Double Out":
            is = getAssets().open("double_check_outs.json");
            break;
        case "Triple Out":
            is = getAssets().open("triple_check_outs.json");
            break;
    }

    int size = is.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    is.read(buffer);
    is.close();
    json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

    hashMap = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType());
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have to admit, I don't fully understand that code snippet and found parts of it online.

I know that I can do things like `System.out.printIn(hashMap.keySet())` or `System.out.printIn(hashMap.values())` but still I don't understand how to get a specific value even though I've been reading through multiple topics here.

If I wanted to get the "3 darts hint" value ("D1") from the key "2", how would I do that?
Is my HashMap<String, Object> formatted correctly to be able to do that?

Comment: Looks like what you really have is a Map of Maps. Id try changing 
new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() 
to 
new TypeToken<HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>().

Then,
hashMap.get("2").get("3 darts hint");

Comment: Great, that works! Thank you!
Edit: you forgot 1 >, it has to be >>> at the end.

Comment: Ah my mistake. Copy and paste negligence ;)

Comment: There is no need to muck around with a buffer. You can do `StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).transferTo(sw); json = sw.toString();`

Comment: @DavidConrad I need something compatible for API 16 and ```StandardCharsets.UTF``` requires API 19.

Comment: @Blaupunkt Well, then, you'll have to keep using `"UTF-8"` and deal with the potential exception. That's unfortunate.

Comment: @DavidConrad In which case would I get an exception?

Comment: @Blaupunkt You would never get an exception for "UTF-8" since it's one of the charsets that is guaranteed to come with Java, but when you use the overloads that take strings to specify the character set, they have to take into account that an unknown charset might be specified so they are declared as `throws UnsupportedEncodingException`.